# Access an (already opened) OpenFileDialog using VBA

Tags: windows, winapi, vba

I am doing some web scraping using excel vba.

At one point in my program my internet explorer instance opens an OpenFileDialog. I need to access this dialog and provide it with a filename. Is there a way to do this in vba?

My idea was to get the window handle (I've already done that) and then somehow get the object using the handle, but i cannot find a way to use the handle to access the window.

Comment: If this were possible, you could turn any scripting language into a virus that steals information from to user's machine.  So it isn't possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have the **hWind** of the dialag box, then the function

```
Private Declare Function PostMessage Lib "user32" Alias "PostMessageA" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, _
 ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
```

will allow you to send keys to the application with

```
Debug.Print PostMessage(hWind, WM_KEYDOWN, vbKeyA, 0)
```

more info [here](http://fracta.net/fracta/index.php/forum/2-excel-vba-forum/8-excel-vba-send-keys-to-another-application-using-vba-sendkeys-command-and-user32dll-postmessage)